# How to hide and visible the menu item icons on clicking?

Tags: android

Am developing a live streaming radio and i gave controls in Action Bar icons like play and stop icons through menu items. All these items work perfectly. what i want is that when i start my app it will show only play icon item and when i click the play icon, stream get starts and stop icon will appear instead of play...and when i press the stop icon  then play icon appears.like in media players when music is playing then pause button appear and when press the pause button play button appears.
i could not get any solution for this and i spend my whole day on this...please Help me to get the solution

This is the XML Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
     <item
       android:id="@+id/play"
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_play"
       app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
       android:title="Play" />
    <item
       android:id="@+id/pause"
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_pause"
       app:showAsAction="always"
       android:title="Pause" />
 </menu>
```

And this is my Main Activity Code

```
//STARTING GET MEDIA FUNCTION
private void getMedia() {
    try {
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        url = new URL(address);
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(String.valueOf(url));
        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                return false;
            }
        });

      mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                bConnected = true;
                if (bShouldPlay) {
                    mediaPlayer.start();

                }
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Connected...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

//ONCREATE FUNCTION START
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    bConnected = false;
    bShouldPlay = false;
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    private Document Getdata() {
       try {
        url = new URL(address);
        connection= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
        builderFactory= DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        builder= builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        xmlDoc = builder.parse(inputStream);
        return xmlDoc;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    inflator.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    bConnected = false;
    bShouldPlay = false;

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.actionPlay:
            if (bConnected) {
                mediaPlayer.start();

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Playing...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else {

                bShouldPlay = true;
                getMedia();
       Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Still connecting...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Connected...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;

case R.id.actionStop:
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Stopping Media Player....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                mediaPlayer.release();
                bConnected = false;
                bShouldPlay = false;
                Toast.makeText(this, "Media Player is Stopped....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

please help me to solve this..

Comment: get buttons using  findViewById(R.id.play) and  findViewById(R.id.stop) and set their visibility to GONE or VISIBLE

Answer (score 0):

one menu item will do ,simply change the menu layout dynamically like below:

```
 private boolean isPlay = false;
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.your_menu, menu);
    MenuItem Item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_play_pause);

    Item.setActionView(R.layout.play);
    Item.getActionView().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
             if(isPlay){
                 Item.setActionView(R.id.pause); //image view with pause icon
             }else {
                 Item.setActionView(R.id.play); //image view with play icon
             }
             isPlay = !isPlay;
        }
    });
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Sir i have not id like (R.id.action_play_pause) and  have not R.layout.play option in code..please can you more elaborate your points...

Comment: sry..i thought you could understand my sample, let me explain it,R.layout.play is an image view with play icon,R.layout.pause is an image view with pause icon,you need to create these 2 layout ,R.id.action_play_pause i mean change your menu XML file ,delete one of the menu item  give the left one id action_play_pause or whatever you like @Parv

Comment: its not working.... giving me this errorE/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.akaalcreatives.hiderbar, PID: 24572android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class vector

Answer (score 0):

Another option instead of the one provided by Du.Fantasy is the following:

Firstly you should add the stop button with visibility = GONE to yourxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
 <item
   android:id="@+id/play"
   android:icon="@drawable/ic_play"
   app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
   android:title="Play" />
<item
   android:id="@+id/pause"
   android:icon="@drawable/ic_pause"
   app:showAsAction="always"
   android:title="Pause" />
<item
   android:id="@+id/stop"
   android:icon="@drawable/ic_stop"
   android:visibility="gone"
   android:title="Stop" />

</menu>
```

Then in your code you can get the items by id and set their visibility dynamically to visible or gone like this for example:

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    bConnected = false;
    bShouldPlay = false;

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.actionPlay:
            if (bConnected) {
                mediaPlayer.start();
                item.setVisible(View.GONE);
                menu.findItem(R.id.ic_pause).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                menu.findItem(R.id.ic_stop).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Playing...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else {

                bShouldPlay = true;
                getMedia();
       Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Still connecting...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Connected...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;

case R.id.actionStop:
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                item.setVisible(View.GONE);
                menu.findItem(R.id.ic_play).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                menu.findItem(R.id.ic_pause).setVisibility(View.GONE);

                Toast.makeText(this, "Stopping Media Player....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                mediaPlayer.release();
                bConnected = false;
                bShouldPlay = false;
                Toast.makeText(this, "Media Player is Stopped....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
            break;
        case R.id.actionPause:
            item.setVisible(View.GONE);
            menu.findItem(R.id.ic_play).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            menu.findItem(R.id.ic_stop).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);    
        default:
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

I hope this will help you to understand the idea of hiding and showing some items.

Comment: its not working dear...saying interduce local variable when i write the item.setVisible(View.GONE)..

Comment: okay, so just change item.setVisibility(View.GONE) to 
menu.findItem(R.id.ic_start).setVisibility(View.GONE)